# Database design: Caching total column in orders table

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database for e-commerce application. And I have two tables

```
orders_table
-order_id

order_details_table
-order_id
-quantity
-price
```

Now I can get total with query. But order total is something that is not changed when order is shipped. And calculating it every time is waste or resources. So I'm wandering is it good idea and good practice to cache order total in orders table?

Something like that:

```
orders_table
-order_id
-total
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: As with most SQL questions, the answer is "it depends".  How often do you expect to need the order total, and how hard, really, is it to calculate on the fly?  I, personally, would not cache the value, but I've seen systems that did.

Comment: There is a fundamental tradeoff in IT - space vs time. If you want to cache the order total you will have to waste 4 bytes for a single-precision or 8 bytes for double-precision value. IF you value the time/speed more than the storage space - then definitely DO cache those values.